# Can TeamViewer host PC steal what I type? /keylogg me?

Tags: authentication, passwords, teamviewer

I was connected to a computer and left it running in the background, I was using Teamviewer to connect to another machine which I was in control of. However, I had to switch back to my machine to check my emails but I was not logged in meaning I had to type my password then I realized that Teamviewer was still running and connected to another.

So I got scared and now I am here wondering, is it possible that the user on the other side could see what I typed on my machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. I don't believe this is at all *possible*. If the other user never had any control over your machine that means they wouldn't even be able to see you using your PC in their TeamViewer session. What you're describing is not possible.

As you had full control and never granted control to your machine as you've explained it would be impossible for the other user to somehow "gain access" or "see your computer" and what you typed. Nor would they have had a chance to install some kind of keylogger unless you explicitly downloaded and ran it.

Comment: so even though I have been in control of other user's PC and minimized teamviewer and on my machine typed password to login somewhere. The user could in no way ,even if he had some special software installed on HIS machine, get my password or my key strokes logged? Because you know, there was connection between our two PCs even though I was the one in control of his. Still just curious

Comment: If you never gave the other user control of your machine nor did you download anything or clicked anything they sent you / ran a program they told you to. Then this isn't possible. If they never had any form of access to your machine how could they get the password? They wouldn't even see you typing it because you're controlling *their* machine not the other way round.

Comment: Thank you. So teamviewer works, that he grants full control only to the user who is connecting to other user right? And the one in danger is the one who is giving access to their PC via letting other user  connect right?

Comment: TeamViewer is a tool for remote access, the only way for someone to have remote access to your machine via TeamViewer is if you grant that access. As you were accessing another users machine and you did *not* grant that user access to your machine there is no way of him gaining control unless you installed something or granted him access. You're correct in saying that technically the user that is having their PC controlled is the one "in danger" in this scenario, yes.